# Conditionally Format Minimum, Unique Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to conditionally format a column so the minimum, unique value is highlighted.

So, for instance if the column looked like:

```
1
1
2
3
```

2 would be the minimum of the unique values. So, I'm trying to conditionally format the cell containing the number 2 in this example.

I've been at this now for hours. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with just one conditional formatting formula. Here's a solution though: Use this array formula to find the lowest unique value:

```
=INDEX(A1:A4,MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A4,A1:A4)=1,A1:A4,"")),A1:A4,0))
```

Be sure to confirm the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Then use conditional formatting to format a cell with that value. So if you put that formula in B1, your conditional formatting looks like this (note the $'s):

```
=IF($A1=$B$1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: I can't see a way of doing it without a helper cell either. Thanks for your fine solution. +1

Comment: I was able to create a Named Range and insert your formula. Thus, no spare cell to hold the formula is required. Worked perfectly!